# Camera2 API - Android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to use new camera api provided by android as camera2. But

```
CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
```

showing error. Does any one have worked on this api.

Have been searching for results for could not find any thing yet.

Comment: Can you share the error with us?

Comment: @Binod Did you get this resolved, or perhaps we can guide you to it now that the SDK has been out for a while now?

Comment: I went with the old camera api at that time. I will be good if you can guide so that others can get benefited.

Answer (score 7):

Binod,

That will only works if your platform support API level 21 - that is the one come after Android L release.

For a detailed explanation of how camera 2 API works, you may want to [take a look at this article](http://pierrchen.blogspot.com.au/2015/01/android-camera2-api-explained.html)

Comment: @JoeBlow yes, you are right. That's the official example you can rely on. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

you can view this example may this will help you

Android Camera2Basic Sample

This sample demonstrates the basic use of Camera2 API. Check the source code to see how you can display camera preview and take pictures.
Pre-requisites

```
Android SDK v21
Android Build Tools v21.1.1
Android Support Repository
```

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic

Please check this Github Repo for Android L (API 21) Camera Preview Library PkmX/lcamera

Answer (score 0):

You need to make 2 classes for API 21 and lower, in lower use common Camera object, and in API 21+ you can use Camera2 API